# Pre-compiled Entity Framework 4 Built from Edmx targeting SQL Server Safe for use with SQL CE?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, edmx

I'm using the following T4 template (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx) to pre-compile my Entity Framework 4 "Views" from a EDMX targeting an existing SQL Server 2008 database.

(aside: this does help speed up the performance hit on the first `SaveChanges` -- I have over 200 tables and the first `SaveChanges` went from 10 seconds to 5 seconds -- still not impressed but an improvement).

My question is: are these pre-compiled views still "safe" to use with SQL CE 4 (i.e. in unit tests) or are they tied to SQL Server 2008? I ask because the generated view file appears to contain SQL statements 
and I wonder if they might be provider specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EDMX file has SSDL information which has hard coded provider specific detail. Here are some articles explaining the procedure to change the provider

- [Preparing an Entity Framework model for multi provider support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82017/Preparing-an-Entity-Framework-model-for-multi-prov)
- [Multiple database support with Entity Framework](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx)

Regarding the performance issue you maybe able to split your database into multiple EDMX files. For example having separate contexts for "Marketing" and "Sales".